# How to update the sort order of my models when the position changes

Tags: elixir

So I have a list of products, say 50 of them.

```
def reorder_products(products, product_id, product_index) do
end
```

The products is a list of ecto Product model schemas, that has a sort_order property.

So in the UI the user can drag a product and change the sort order of a given product.  I need to update the records above or below whereever the user wants to insert the product.

So to visual this:

```
id   sort_order
1    1000
2    2000
3    3000
4    4000
5    5000
```

So if the product#5 gets reordered and placed at index position 3, the new list will look like:

```
id   sort_order
1    1000
2    2000
5    5000
3    3000
4    4000
```

So now I have to reorder all rows below that (ignoring the fact I could just change the sort order without changing the others for now)

How could I do that in ecto?

In another language I would do:

```
for(x = 0; x < products.length(); x++)
{
    if x >= 3 {
      products[x].sort_order = x * 1000;
      products[x].save!
    }
}
```

In elixir I would do this, but the ordering is not guaranteed.

```
Enum.map(products, fn p -> 
   p.sort_order = ???  # i need the index position here
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

The function name `map` is not directly related to the data type (i.e., a hash). If you have a list the order is guaranteed. That said you could use https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#with_index/2 but I think a better solution is to use reduce and count as you iterate using:

```
iex(1)> Enum.reduce([1,2,3,4], 0, fn(x, acc) -> IO.inspect({x,acc}); acc + 1 end)
{1, 0}
{2, 1}
{3, 2}
{4, 3}
```

Now, on updating the sort_order of a product you would not assign and save, as the data is immutable. You would perform an update operation on the product using a changeset.

```
 changeset = Product.changeset(product, %{sort_order: x})
 Repo.update(changeset)
```

or in the context of Phoenix and context modules:

```
 Products.update(product, %{sort_order: x})
```

The full documentation can be found here: https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Enum.with_index](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#with_index/2) to get an indexed version first, then use the `map` function. When using the map function there, you can use a guard expression on the index, and differentiate that way when you'd like to update the sort order.

```
products
|> Enum.with_index
|> Enum.map(fn 
             {product, index} when index > 3 -> Map.put(product, :sort_order, index * 1000); 
             {product, index} -> product  
            end)
```

In this example I assumed you use Maps as the query returns, feel free to update it to your needs.

Last bit about saving it, you can take a look at the [update](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#update/3) function.